# How to connect flutter and dart with android studio - path not appearing

Tags: android, windows, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have installed the Flutter SDK on my Windows 10, my Flutter plugin is also installed in Android Studio

[image: Flutter Plugin in Android Studio]

But when I click on "New Flutter Project", I get the following screen:

[image]

Now if I click on flutter, and have to specify its SDK path, I dont see any version report after specifying it.

[image]

On clicking next, I don't get "dart" in the language options.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the screen where you "don't see" dart is completely normal. You are picking what the skeleton languages are going to be in for their respective platforms, there is no where on that screen where it should show dart.

if you open a new flutter project it will be in dart.

You do have two issues that need to be fixed, and thats the cmdline tools and android license but it tells you how to fix it

Comment: Thank you, do I have to add the flutter SDK path every time? And if so, then where do I specify the dart SDK path ?

Comment: when you go to open a new project you should be able to just click new flutter project and then it will show you the same screen with the correct flutter sdk path and just hit next. you shouldnt have to change it every time, it should be correct already. and then the following screen is just to select the different set up options, ie what languages you want the skeletons to be built on and what platforms you want the fltuter project built for ie ios androind macos web etc...

Comment: if that solves it let me know and accept the above answer :) let me know if you have any more questions